# Cshtml-file not rendered in App.razor pipeline in Blazor app

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've been involved in developing a server-side Blazor app (.NET 6.0) and have recently run into an issue in the rendering of a `.cshtml` file.

In `App.razor` we've created a component called `Setup.razor` in which we perform a few tasks that need to happen on page load. One of the things that it does is call a javascript function through interop which applies a `data-bs-theme` attribute to the `html` element in order for it to be applied to all other elements that are rendered as part of the page.

When rendering a `.razor` file as a page, the `<html>` tag successfully receives the attribute. However, when rendering a `.cshtml` file, the attribute is not applied.

My question, then, is: are `.cshtml` pages not rendered the same way as `.razor` pages (i.e. as defined in the component hierarchy defined in `App.razor`)?

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Setup>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <Error Code="NotFound"></Error>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </Setup>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```